# How to delete/remove an object in java so that when using next time compilor throught an error

Tags: java, oop

I have created some objects by using bar function as in code below. f2 points to f1, and f3 points to f2 something like linkedlist. Now i want to remove f2, so i did this f2 = null. But when i am calling the function f3.reveal, it can still see the data of f2.

```
public class prog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bar f1 = new bar(12, null);
        bar f2 = new bar(23, f1);
        bar f3 = new bar(42, f2);
        f2 = null;
        f3.reveal();
    }
}

class bar {
    final int data;
    final bar prev;

    bar(int data, bar prev) {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    void reveal() {
        System.out.println("Value of this object is " + this.data);
        System.out.println("Value of Previous object is " + this.prev.data);
    }
}
```

1. I want to understand why even after setting f2 to null, how can i access f2.data.
2. How can i do it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about variables, objects, and references to objects.

`f2` is simply a variable that refers to an object.  Nulling f2 does nothing to the object and it does not invalidate any other reference to the object, such as `f3.prev`.

`f3.prev` remains a valid reference to the object it previously referred to.

How to do it properly?

That's difficult to say, since your concepts are skewed.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  If your intent is that all references to some object are nulled out, then you have to null out all references to that object (which implies needing to know where all those references might be).

This is not an issue about garbage collection, it is simply that nulling out a single reference does not magically null out all other references.

In your specific case with a linked list, "properly" would be to remove the object from the list (so there are no `prev` links to it) and then null out `f2`.

Comment: That was a really nice explanation. So i got the 1st part but is there a way i can accomplish that, like deleting the object directly instead of its reference.

Comment: so this.prev is also a reference and if i set it to null i can do it only by creating a method which will set it to null. but than i will have to call that method on f3

Comment: You should look at it at a higher level.  Don't think in terms of "nulling out a reference".  You have put your object into a list. You will (quite sensibly) be able to find your object in the list until you actually remove it from the list. Your first job is to write a 'remove' method.

Answer (score 0):

It you are trying to create a linkedlist then to remove it completely you have to remove the reference from pre and post node as well.
Which means you must enter f1 in f3 prev address.

Comment: no i am not trying to create a linked list that was just for the reference

Comment: Even though you are not trying to create a linked list. Your object is not garbage collected until it is refered by some other object. Hence you have to remove that reference first to make it garbage collected.

Comment: that's the only point i can't use garbage collector. So i want an NullPointer exception when i call a method on null

Comment: did u try by removing the ref of f2 from f3.

Comment: You're not "calling a method on null" -- f3.prev is not null. You have not written any code to make f3.prev be null.  You only wrote code to set f2 null.